# Request method of wp setting and option api

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am building a plugin. For rendering the menu page both Option API & Setting API are used. Below is my callback function for `add_menu_page()`

```
<?php
//Calback function for add menu page

function render_newsletter_admin() {
  if(!current_user_can( 'manage_options' )){
    return;
  }
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
   
    add_settings_error( 'newsletter', 'newsletter', __( 'Settings Saved', 'victory' ), 'success' );
    settings_errors(  );
  }
      ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      
        <form action="options.php" method="post">
            <?php
            // output security fields for the registered setting "wporg"
            settings_fields( 'newsletter' );
            // output setting sections and their fields
            // (sections are registered for "wporg", each field is registered to a specific section)
            do_settings_sections( 'newsletter' );
            // output save settings button
            submit_button( 'Save Settings' );
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Notice that method attribute of the form set to `POST` but to add setting error `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"` is being checked and it is working. Shouldn't it be checked against `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be checked against `POST`?

It's checked against GET instead of POST because the form is being submitted to and handled by `options.php` (or more precisely, `wp-admin/options.php`), and after the submission is processed, WordPress will **redirect** the user back to the origin of the submission which is the menu page having that form. Therefore the request method would then be GET.

**Illustration of how the request method changed** (from `GET` to `POST` then back to `GET`)

1. User landed on the menu page (the request method is GET).
2. Then he/she submitted the form.
3. The browser submits the form to `options.php`, using the POST method.
4. Now on the `options.php` page, the request method *is POST*.
5. And after the form submission is processed, WordPress sends the user back to the menu/form page.
6. Now on the menu page, the request method is GET because the above redirect uses that method.

**Relevant code in `wp-admin/options.php`**

- So at the top in [`wp-admin/options.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-admin/options.php), it says...

  ```php
  /**
   * Options Management Administration Screen.
   *
   * If accessed directly in a browser this page shows a list of all saved options
   * along with editable fields for their values. Serialized data is not supported
   * and there is no way to remove options via this page. It is not linked to from
   * anywhere else in the admin.
   *
   * This file is also the target of the forms in core and custom options pages
   * that use the Settings API. In this case it saves the new option values
   * and returns the user to their page of origin.
   *
   * @package WordPress
   * @subpackage Administration
   */
  ```
- And on lines 339-341 (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-admin/options.php#L339):

  ```php
  // Redirect back to the settings page that was submitted.
  $goback = add_query_arg( 'settings-updated', 'true', wp_get_referer() );
  wp_redirect( $goback );
  ```

And if you look at the "[complete example](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/)" in the [plugin developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/), it's actually also checking against GET whereby [`add_settings_error()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_error/) is called only if `$_GET['settings-updated']` is set:

```php
// add error/update messages

// check if the user have submitted the settings
// WordPress will add the "settings-updated" $_GET parameter to the url
if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
    // add settings saved message with the class of "updated"
    add_settings_error( 'wporg_messages', 'wporg_message', __( 'Settings Saved', 'wporg' ), 'updated' );
}

// show error/update messages
settings_errors( 'wporg_messages' );
```

Also, you might want to call [`settings_errors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/settings_errors/) outside the `if` (like above), and pass `newsletter` as the first parameter for the function, i.e. do `settings_errors( 'newsletter' )`.